# Can I pass different types of parameters to an AsyncTask in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I want to implement a generic, thread save class which takes the RessourceId of an ImageView and the Url (http) where the desired image file is stored. It'll download the image and fills the src of the ImageView in the UiThread.

I thought [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) would be the best thing for me. However I noticed that I only can pass one type of parameters to the `doInBackground()` Method. Like an Array of Urls. Is that true? What would u suggest me?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add setter methods to your `AsyncTask` implementation, or even define your own constructor to pass additional parameters.

Optionally, if your `AsyncTask` implementation is an inner class of an activity you can access all the instance variables of your activity. I prefer the above option myself, as it clearly indicates which data the task requires.

Answer (score 55):

You can pass params as objects

```
new MyTask().execute(url, str, context);

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
            Url url = (Url) params[0];
            String str = (String) params[1];
            Context ctx = (Context) params[2];

            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but then it will not be type safe.

Comment: This is great :)

Comment: The accepted answer here is type safe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989914/how-to-pass-in-two-different-data-types-to-asynctask-android